# How do I split a ISO 8601 date/time column in UNIX?

Tags: unix

I'm trying to split a column that has a date/time in the following format: `2019-01-01 16:40:50`

I'd like to split it into 4 separate columns for Year, Month, Date, Start Hour. What would be the best way to do it on command line?

Comment: Please clarify. What do you mean by "UNIX"? (e.g. your interactive shell? a shell script? what environment? what language?). What do you mean by a "column"? In a relational database table? In a CSV file? In a HTML table? Why do you want to split a date-time value anyway? Date-time values should be treated as atomic values: their constituent components should only be extracted for human consumption purposes.

Comment: On the command line interface. It's a CSV file. I specifically need the date, month and start hour.